# R - Importing Multiple Tables from a Single CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I was hoping there may be a way to do this, but after trying for a while I have had no luck.

I am working with a datafile (`.csv` format) that is being supplied with multiple tables in a single file.  Each table has its own header row, and data associated with it.  Is there a way to import this file and create separate data frames for each header/dataset?

Any help or ideas that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

A sample of the datafile and it's structure can be found [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqve4dwk5ms1k5j/2015-03-23-1300_Indoor_Cycling_WF.csv?dl=0)

---

When trying to use `read.csv` I get the following error:

> "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     more columns than column names"

Comment: The sample csv file loads fine for me with `read.csv`. I can't see any separate tables, though.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, looks like I had uploaded an edited version of the file that I had been using to move forward with some of the data manipulation. The original raw file should be available from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqve4dwk5ms1k5j/2015-03-23-1300_Indoor_Cycling_WF.csv?dl=0). I have fixed the original post as well. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the help for `read.table`:

- `nrows`: number of rows to parse
- `skip`: number of rows to skip

You can parse your file as follows:

```
first <- read.table(myFile, nrows=2)
second <- read.table(myFile, skip=3, nrows=2)
third <- read.table(myFile, skip=6, nrows=8)
```

You can always automate this by using `grep()` to search for the table seperators.

You can also read the table using `fill=TRUE`, and then split out the tables afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfect, I ended up using grep to search for the header rows and skipping to those points in the file. it also allowed me to do the math to see how many rows should be loaded per table.

ie.
`lap_count <- workout_start - laps_start - 2;
lap_data <- read.csv(file_name, header=TRUE, colClasses="numeric", skip=laps_start, nrows=lap_count);`